# How to remove duplicate characters in a string C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string from Listview

```
String str = "4710105011011,4710265849066,4712019100607,4710168702901,4710431339148,4710043552065";
```

How can I remove character ',' in this string?

Comment: `str = str.Replace(",","");`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does it...

```
str = str.Replace(",","");
```

...becuase the first parameter "," is the part you want to replace and the second "" is what you want it to replace with.